# Exactly when is an object modifiable?

Tags: c++

Like, it cannot be said that cv-qualified variables are unmodifiable, because at construction, they are. So when exactly is an object modifiable? Of course, I know that an object is modifiable when it can be modified, but it Is a little confusing to me because then you could say that all cv-qualified variables are modifiable...

Comment: After the closing brace of the c'tor, until the opening brace of the d'tor. That's it.

Comment: Please edit your question - expressions are never modifiable.

Comment: @StoryTeller wouldn't that be wrong to say since cv-qualified variables are not modifiable after construction, right?

Comment: @npp - You do realize that "after construction" is "after the closing brace of the constructor", right?

Comment: @StoryTeller although an object need not be of a type that has a constructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza - Trivially constructible is still constructible :)

Comment: @npp You could say that before construction, a "variable" doesn't exist.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sure, but you did mention constructors and closing braces :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza - It's a closing brace in spirit :)

Comment: This sounds a bit like nit-picking pedantry tbh.

Comment: You can modify an object when you have a not const qualified reference to it. Notice that in object constructor current object reference is never const qualified. Const qualifier is only applied to the variable being constructed. cv-qualified variable does not mean that object being referenced is not modifiable at all, it only mean that it can not be modified using this variable. Unfortunately C++ does not have means to express a "strong" kind const correctness / immutability.

Comment: A "strong" kind of const is when an object is created const. Then by definition no non-const reference to it can exist (without invoking UB).

Comment: @NeilButterworth then why can you say "modifiable lvalue" when "lvalue" is an expression?

Comment: @Fac Pam The result of evaluating an expression may be modifiable - the expression isn't.

Comment: @NeilButterworth but an lvalue is not the result of the evaluation, but it is an _expression_, but a name of certain expressions that designate objects and functions, so is it not wrong to say that lvalues can be modifiable? Wouldn't that be the same as saying the expressions that designate objects or functions can be modifiable?